# How to map Fixed Versions of a java bug to release?

Tags: java

I am looking at some java bugs.

For example, one below is fixed by 7(b14).  How can I find the JDK (Oracle or OpenJDK) version matching it?

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6533413

[image]

Comment: Very interesting from oracle.com:

Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 55 (JDK 7u55)
The full version string for this update release is 1.7.0_55-b13 (where "b" means "build"), except for online 32bit JRE installers and Auto Update mechanisms for Windows, where the version string is 1.7.0_55-b14. The version number is 7u55.

Is 7u55 b13 or b14?

Comment: Similarly frustrating / confusing, the [tags](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/tags) in Mercurial reference build numbers, but don't seem to correlate to the build numbers in JDK bugs or actual releases.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, it's better to use the OpenJDK bug system. You can find there the [equivalent page for your bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6533413?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel).

There you can click on the **Fix Version** label and obtain the page corresponding to the [JDK 7 without updates](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK/fixforversion/11810)

If you look in the mercurial repository, you will see that the tags for [build numbers](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/tags) are from **jdk7-b24** to **jdk7-b147**

**So it means that the build b14 is already integrated into the initial release of the JDK7.**